# How to generalize login steps in Selenium Cucumber and avoid repetitive steps in feature file?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am using Selenium+Cucumber for my automation project and written using Java. I have written a feature file in which I have 4-5 login steps repeated in every scenario. Below are the login lines that are getting repeated in every scenario.

```
Scenario: Display the relevant items assigned when logged in as an testUser
    Given I am on the login page
    And I fill email with valid testUser email address
    And I fill password with valid testUser password
    And I press Log in
    When I click on the selector
    Then I should see all the items assigned to my testUser account
```

Here the keywork "testUser" is parameterized. Sometimes the same steps would be repeated with another user such as "stageUser". For such kind of steps, does Cucumber provide a way to generalize these steps in some way? Because each scenario begins with these 6 lines thus making the scearios look bigger and with these repetitive steps.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider moving the common steps to a background.
Seems like a bit of a hack but you can mention the user in the description of the Scenario as below.

```
  Background: 
    Given Do given
    When Do when
    Then Do then

  Scenario: User is - Test User One
    And user name is

  Scenario: User is - Test User Two
    And user name is
```

Then capture this user in the Before hook. The user will then be available across steps in the scenario.

```
private String user;

@Before
public void before(Scenario scen) {
    this.user = scen.getName().substring(scen.getName().indexOf('-') + 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write better scenarios and steps. Yours are all about HOW you are logging in so the repetition is painful. Instead write steps that are only about WHAT you are doing; these are easier to reuse.

So ...

```
Scenario: Login
  Given I am registered
  When I login
  Then I should be logged in
```

then later

```
Feature: Something that requires me to be logged in

Background
  Given I am logged in

Scenario: Do something
  When I do something
  Then something should be done
```

See how I have reduced the big pile of background into something much simpler and abstract.

I'll give a few hints on implementation here

```
Given I am logged in
  @i = create_registered_user
  login(user: @i
end

When I login
  login(user: @i)
end

Given I am registered
  @i = create_registered_user
end
```

You can apply this approach with any level of complexity. Note how in the last scenario are using our relatively complex behaviour of registering without the scenario or feature even being aware of it (registration is part of login).

Answer (score 0):

Use @Before and @After annotations for running before and after each scenario respectively. In cases when we need to perform some global setup/cleanup: @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite

Comment: you mean in the Java class right? Even then how would I parameterise the email address/username? because it changes from scenario to scenario though the steps are the same

Comment: Do you think it would make sense to divide those scenarios into different feature files? To keep scenarios for only one user separately from scenarios for multiple users, and parameterize @before steps in the second file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Valentyna, but considering the page object model I am using, it wouldn't make much sense for me :(